# How to implement a strange for loop

Tags: c++

Is it possible to create a loop pattern that will allow me to change operators?

Like this

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
auto test(T1 a, T2 b, T3 c, T4 x)
{
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;

    for (; a c b; a x)
    {
        cout << a << " |a " << this_thread::get_id() << "\n" << endl;
    }
}

// main
// test(2.242, <, 20, ++);
```

Comment: Pass a predicate.

Comment: @Fureeish: I started hacking before reading your comment ;) Sorry for the stolen answer :-)

Comment: @Klaus I don't mind, I would've provided a very similar one :>

Comment: @Fureeish: It's because its a natural one!? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can pass any kind of function to your template. Here I use lambdas for that purpose.

As the lambdas itself are templated, you can use any kind of types in your loop.
In the loop itself we simply call the given functions. Thats easy? ;)

```
template <typename VAR_TYPE1, typename VAR_TYPE2, typename PREDICATE_TYPE, typename INCREMENT_FUNC_TYPE>
auto test(VAR_TYPE1 a, VAR_TYPE2 b, PREDICATE_TYPE predicate, INCREMENT_FUNC_TYPE incrementFunc )
{   
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    // we simply call the given functions for the predicate/condition and the increment 
    for (; predicate(a,b); incrementFunc(a) )
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
}   



int main()
{   
    // use with lambdas
    test( 1,9, []( auto a, auto b){ return a < b; }, []( auto& a ) { return a++; });   
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // use with stl defined predicates
    test( 1,9, std::less{} , []( auto& a ) { return a++; });   
    std::cout << std::endl;
    test( 10.1, 5.5, std::greater{} , []( auto& a ) { return a-=0.2; });   
}
```

Comment: Regarding the most popular operators, for instance the `<` used here, I think it'd be more readable to replace the first lambda with `std::less<>{}`, but that could be a matter of taste. For beginners though, it would indicate that standard library has some of those already. +1 nonetheless!

Comment: An interesting way, thanks for the answer. Are there any other options for implementation?

Comment: @Fureeish: Thanks for the hint, added it as an additional example.

Comment: If the lambda is made in the form of a template, is it possible to make the code more elegant?

Comment: @chip: There are millions of other possibilities. But this is a quite common approach. You can also remove the "free template parms" and make them directly only accepting the functions signature like fn(T1,T2) and so on... But with a template which except everything you are free to use also lambdas which is a plus for me.

Comment: @klaus More abbreviated implementation, as much as possible less code.

Comment: I figured out thanks again, the only thing that confuses me a bit is

`for (; c (a, b); x (a))` <-- I'm confused here

Comment: It would confuse me also ;) I will write it more explanatory

Comment: @chip ... done. In hope that now it becomes clear, that we simply call functions inside  `for()` to calculate the condition and increment part of the statement.

Comment: @klaus I have another question, can this cause recursion?

Comment: @chip: yes, if one of the both given functions itself call `test` again.

Comment: @klaus Interestingly, if optimized, would using pure recursion instead of a for loop be faster?

Comment: Suggest changing `incrementFunc(a)` to `a = incrementFunc(a)`.   The first will result in an infinite loop if `incrementFunc()` accepts an argument by value.